# Is it possible that MongoDB immediately writes on the disk and does not store the informations in the memory?

Tags: database, mongodb, memory, shutdown

Under Windows 10, I am using MongoDB 4.0.0 Community Edition (standalone) installation and with the help of the Windows task scheduler I regularly run a task which updates my database by adding new records.

The storage system currently in use is Wired Tiger. After the last, unclean system shutdown (a simple Windows restart), all database information was lost. I was unable to recover it by repairing the database as described under https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/.

Is there any way of configuring Mongo to not store the information in memory after the updates, but immediately writing it to disk without the need to cleanly shut down the database and restart it manually? What are best practices here?